# настройка HTTP cookie manager

Tags: jmeter

Есть post запрос в котором пробрасывается логин/пароль и получается токен.

http://joxi.ru/krDM6EatEM4WZm

Хочу сохранить куку, и вроде даже получается (на скрине видно), но видимо она некорректно сохраняется, ибо в другие запросах ошибка "Session ID unknown".
В cookei manager значение Cookie policy установлено на standart.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы сохранить куку в [переменную](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) вам нужно добавить следующую строку в файл *user.properties*

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
```

Потом можно будет получить значение через переменную`${COOKIE_KC_RESTART}`. На всякий случай можно еще добавить вот эту строку

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

таким образом JMeter будет игнорировать возможные ошибки.

Более подробная информация:

- [Miscellaneous configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

---

Также стоит проверить параметры самого запроса: `code` и `execution`, они выглядят так, как будто каждый раз новые. Скорее всего их нужно будет вытаскивать из предыдущего ответа каким-нибудь [пост-процессором](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).